# Smiley icons (emoticons) select all and replace in Android Edit text

Tags: android-edittext

I am doing Build Spannable text using ImageSpan and then setText the Spannable to EditText for displaying Emoticons in Edittext. It is working fine.
But I am facing a problem when I enter few emoticons and long press edittext field and select all. Then press a character on the keypad to replace all the emoticons with the character.
It is not able to replace the emoticons with the entered character on the keypad. It is showing first emoticon in the edittext field.

Only onTextChanged() API is getting called, In that the CharSequence is received correctly with the entered letter on the keypad. But displays the first emoticon only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue in Android. EditText need to take care of select all and replace.
I also had the same issue.
After entering smiley icons, Select all and if you try to replace it with another smiley icon,
it replaces fine. In the edittext, enter a character first and enter emoticons, then select all and replace then also it works fine.
Problem occures when you try to replace smiley icon(s). Since we are receiving replaced letter on the android 
`onTextChanged()` call back, Android platform need to take care of that.